# mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time

Tags: mysql

I forgot my MySQL password, and following these steps to reset it...
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-and-reset-a-root-password-in-mysql#how-to-reset-a-root-password-

When I type that command....

```
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

I get that message... How I fix it?

> 150924 14:01:12 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the
>   same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog
>   to take effect. 150924 14:01:12 mysqld_safe Logging to
>   '/var/log/mysql/error.log'. 150924 14:01:12 mysqld_safe A mysqld
>   process already exists